# node-sass - How to use a wildcard directory value in output path

Tags: javascript, sass, node-sass

Is there a way for `node-sass` to use the variable in it's output path? I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
node-sass blocks/**/editor.scss -o dist/$1-editor.css
```

The goal is to prefix the output with the value of it's parent directory. For example, a directory structure of:

```
blocks
├── foo
│   ├── editor.scss
├── bar
│   ├── editor.scss
└── baz
    └── editor.scss
```

would result in the following compiled CSS filenames:

```
dist
├── foo-editor.css
├── bar-editor.css
└── baz-editor.css
```

The above command currently outputs:

```
dist
└── -editor.css
```

The `$1` prefix is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, this can be done in node.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const sass = require("node-sass");

fs.readdirSync("blocks").forEach(dir => {
  sass.render(
    {
      file: `blocks/${dir}/editor.scss`,
      outFile: `dist/${dir}-editor.css`
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (!error) {
        fs.writeFile(`dist/${dir}-editor.css`, result.css, error => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(`dist/${dir}-editor.css`);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```